# match varchar data php

Tags: php, html, mysql, varchar

I've done a little bit of digging around but I'm not entirely sure what i'm searching for. I've been around some documentation for keywords like 'match' but I haven't found anything that does what I need.

In simple, I've got a simple CMS for a Blog and I'm currently in the process of adding Tag functionality. I.e. Web Design, Php Rules etc.

I've got a line of code under a fetch:

```
echo '<a href="tags.php">' . str_replace(',', '</a> <a href="tags.php"> ', $post['Tags']) . '</a>' . '</div></div>';
```

This gives me the result:
http://gyazo.com/27c3474767a4b9dd46ab4f69c2a50a6d

Which is what I want but I'm unsure if this will work well as explained:

The anchor in my echo references tags.php and this is where my problem begins. In phpMyAdmin I've got a table called posts, in here I've got a column called tags under variable type varchar.

I was wondering if there was a method or function in PHP that would allow me to compare the varchar that was clicked to other varchars in that column and then echo out all of the matching results. Thus when user clicks on Tag A, only blog posts with Tag A will appear on the page tags.php.

I assume that I would need to pass the anchor as a variable somehow into a function on tags.php and perform an if (condition == conditional) test. But I'm unsure on how to pass the 'Tags' specific information to the function in order to process it.

Comment: if you're storing multiple tags in a single field, then your database design is incorrect, and should be normalized so each tag exists in is own dedicated record in a child table.

Comment: I had a funny feeling that this was the case, it felt wrong that it was being stored like that. Do you have any recommendation for how I should design my DB? I understand that to PHP Tag A and Tag B just look like Data 1 and Data 1 to it.

Comment: Generally speaking, 3rd normal form is a good design to aim for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: At first I was confused but after looking at the examples I think I realize. I have an alternative plan that I can do with my knowledge of PHP but it's still not what I want. If I made a separate table named Tags, how would I store the tags as their own records? The only way I know how to do this would be to add Tag information manually and then reference it later with drop down lists. Which I don't mind, but for the sakes of going the extra mile I would want a tag system similar to Stack Overflows with comma separation.

Comment: Actually I think I've worked it out, thanks a lot for the help Marc.